Error flutter build "build linux" only supported on Linux hosts
I have tried to get flutter to build the project, but it will not allow me to build it for linux.

I have tried master channel, upgrading, flutter clean etc.
I do not have any errors when I run Flutter doctor - v
I have upgraded to the latest flutter.
I am just having a hard time understanding the reasons it will not run the build.
I have removed all plug-ins that are not being used and I believe all the plugins are compatible.
Edit:
My apologies I am using MACOS running on Android Studio
/Users//development/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.27.0-1.0.pre.295, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale en-AU)
• Flutter version 3.27.0-1.0.pre.295 on channel master at /Users/*/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 47318592d1 (3 hours ago), 2024-10-29 19:01:25 -0400
• Engine revision 999797a2f6
• Dart version 3.7.0 (build 3.7.0-78.0.dev)
• DevTools version 2.40.1
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/*****/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-35, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 16B40
• CocoaPods version 1.14.3
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.98.0
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
• **** iPad (2) (mobile)                • iOS 17.6.1 21G93
• **** (mobile)                         • iOS 17.6.1 21G93
• macOS (desktop)                 • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64
• Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad     • darwin         • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)                    • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.70
[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0

what is your os? and can you provide your flutter doctor?

Yes, you're on a mac.  You cannot build for linux.  You must use a VM, or a CI/CD system that supports that, like Github Actions.

I honestly thought I would build it as a package and then deploy to the vm.  I think I have over thought the whole issue.
